# TCPConn SetWriteDeadline not working

Tags: networking, go, tcp, network-programming, timeout

I'm writing a TCP client in **Golang**. The server will never send any replies, or any data.

As soon as I fail to write after a given timeout I want the client to close the connection.

So from reading the documentation for `SetWriteDeadline` in `Conn`:
https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn

```
    // SetWriteDeadline sets the deadline for future Write calls
    // and any currently-blocked Write call.
    // Even if write times out, it may return n > 0, indicating that
    // some of the data was successfully written.
    // A zero value for t means Write will not time out.
    SetWriteDeadline(t time.Time) error
```

From the above description I use it like this:

```
...
for {
    select {
    case msg := <-messages:
        conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(1 * time.Second))

        // When server goes away this just blocks forever. No timeout!
        n, err := conn.Write(msg.ByteArray())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        log.Printf("Sent %v bytes\n", n)
    }
}
...
```

But the timeout is never triggered if the server goes away, instead the `Write` call will just block forever.

- What am I doing wrong with `SetWriteDeadline`?
- I want to kill the connection if the Write does not finish within the given timeout no matter what, if `SetWriteDeadline` is not the proper way to do that, how do I do it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The Write call is blocking on the send, yet it does not timeout with an error as I understand it's supposed to? I don't care about ACK or anything. If the call takes longer than 1 second for ANY reason I want to return.

Comment: Are you certain that it’s actually blocked on the write? I would check with a stack trace. If not try to make a [mcve], since this should not block.

Comment: "_I'm writing a TCP client..._" TCP doesn't have clients or servers, that is an application concept. TCP creates peer connections.

Comment: Hmmm I was running the client wrapped in a function that will reconnect. When I removed it from that the timeout now works. However, no defer is run when returning from the function on error.

Comment: @RonMaupin it's a client in the context of the protocol in question (Open Pixel Control), but sure.

Comment: @JimB the minimal viable example helped me find the issue, which turned out to be a deadlock. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a deadlock issue.

My program was using a lock each time it was sending on the `messages` channel using the Fanout pattern.

The problem was that when I was returning the `err` on the Write timeout there was a `defer` call that attempted to lock that same `Mutex`. Since I did not get the output I was expecting I thought the timeout never triggered.

```
defer func() {
    thing.ThatCreatedDeadlock()
    log.Println("Expected to see this")
}
```

So simply logging on the `Write` error directly would have made this obvious:

```
    n, err := conn.Write(msg.ByteArray())
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return err
    }
```